# Class not found when unmarshalling: com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D$SavedState?

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I am using banner ads from StartApp which is giving me the titled exception.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I have three fragments which I use to populate PageTabStrip above

**fragment1_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner
            android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragments2_layout.xml and fragment3_layout.xml are exactly same as fragment1_layout.xml**

**Fragment1.java**

```
    public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment
    {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
        }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
                //Initializing list_fragment1 in fragment1_layout.xml here
    }
}
```

**Similarly I have Fragment2.java and Fragment3.java classes**

**CollectionPagerAdapter.java**

```
class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter 
{
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int tabNumber) 
    {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch( tabNumber )
        {
            case 0: fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;

            case 1: fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;

            case 2: fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;  
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    { 
        return activity.getResources().getInteger( R.integer.number_of_tabs );
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
    {
        //Returning titles here     
    }
 }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
    { 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Has to be called before setContentView() method
        StartAppAd.init( this, getString(R.string.my_startapp_developer_id), getString(R.string.my_apps_startapp_id) ); 
        startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);  //For Interstitial Ads
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CollectionPagerAdapter collectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter( this, getSupportFragmentManager() );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        startAppAd.onBackPressed();
        super.onBackPressed();
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        startAppAd.onResume();  //For Interstitial Ads
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
        startAppAd.onPause();   //Makes the Interstitial Ads appear when the user press the 'Home' button on the device
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
    }
}
```

When I run my app up fresh i.e., the with no previously saved state. The banner ads get shown in there respective PageTabStrip and everything runs fine.

Consider I am in **Fragement1** PageTabStripe and press the 'Home' key(so that the app saves its state) to get out of my app and then come back to it at a later stage, after running a few other app (so as to execute **protected void onDestroy()** in MainActivity of my app). The **Fragment1** PageTabStrip gets restored properly but when I swipe to **Fragment2** PageTabStrip, my app crashes with the exception below.

The same thing happens when I am in **Fragment3** PageTabStrip, press the 'Home' key to get out of my app and come back it at a later stage. **Fragment3** PageTabStrip gets restored properly but when I swipe to **Fragment2** PageTabStrip, my app crashes with the following exception.

Class not found when unmarshalling:

```
com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D$SavedState
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D$SavedState
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2129)
12-09 at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2093)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2009)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2356)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1731)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2066)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2310)
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:231)
at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1255)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/startapp/android/publish/banner/banner3d/Banner3D$SavedState
... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D$SavedState" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Miki from StartApp.
As we've never encountered the issue you are having and in order for us to be able to further investigate it and help you solve it, please contact our support team by opening a support ticket in our developers portal or by sending us an email to support@startapp.com. Please also attach your project source code or the apk file.

Thanks